# Using getElementsByName in JavaScript, Number of elements keeps increasing in timed loop. Why?

Tags: javascript

This script is updating the images contained on a webpage without having to reload the page.  That part works.

The part that doesn't is that the script seems to store the prior values of var obj and keeps accruing and appending the time so after a couple of passes, I end up with `...png?4314331?5847301?8978123` and it keeps appending.

So if my page has 5 images, after the first 5 seconds has passed, `input.length` will now be 10 and the second 5 seconds, `input.length` returns 15, and so on.

My question is why?

```
<script>
function updateImage() {

   var input = new Array();
   input = document.getElementsByName('imageChart');

   for (var i=0; i < input.length; i++)
   {
     var obj = document.getElementsByName("imageChart").item(i);

     alert(obj.src);  // Just to check what it's doing

     obj.src = obj.src + "?" + Math.random();

     setTimeout("updateImage()",5000);
   }
}
</script>


<body onload="updateImage()">
```

Comment: It's because that's precisely what you're telling your code to do. `obj.src = obj.src + "?" + Math.random();` It assigns to `obj.src` the current value of `obj.src` + a question mark and a number. The current value each time is going to be the result of whatever you assigned the previous time.

Comment: So a question for squint.  It's my understanding that the line you referenced is to help make sure html doesn't use a cached version of the image.  So after the timeout, would I set the obj.src back to the original again?

Also, on successive passes, why does it then find 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc if there are only 5 images?

Comment: You would just set the `obj.src` to the new value. You may need to keep the original path stored when the page loads. But then basically do `obj.src = originalPath + "?" + Math.random()`. I don't know why you're finding more images on each pass. Is there more code?

Comment: As far as scripts, no.  I have some CSS that also involved in the img.  
`<div class='hover_img'><a href='#'>Chart<span><img name='imageChart' src='/TP/images/BCS.png'></span></a></div>`. Note that the `name='imageChart'` is what is looked for in the function.  I use the CSS to show the image on mouseover.

Comment: @squint I'm pretty sure the problem lies with the `setTimeout` and that I'm just not using it properly.  I am doing a lot of searching but not finding how to likely resolve the issue.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `setTimeout` call. I mean some people may complain that you're passing a string, but the call will succeed either way. You could instead call `setTimeout(updateImage, 5000)`, which passes *(not calls)* the function. This is preferred, but shouldn't have any impact on the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the right way, but this is how I ultimately resolved all the issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateImage() {

   var input = new Array();
   input = document.getElementsByName('imageChart');

   for (var i=0; i < input.length; i++)
   {
     var obj = document.getElementsByName("imageChart").item(i);

     var str = obj.src;

     var strSplit = str.split("?");

     obj.src = strSplit[0] + "?" + Math.random();
   }

   setTimeout(function() {updateImage()},10000);

}
</script>
```